# How filter my user list by status ? - Yii

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

I use Yii Framework and I want to filter by status my users list. The status is defined by a number:

- 0 : enabled
- 1 : banned
- 2 : disabled

Therefore display the correct status I use a function itemAlias​() :

```
public static function itemAlias($attribute, $value=null) {

    $_items = array(
        'status' => array(
            '0' => Yii::t("status", 'Enabled'),
            '1' => Yii::t("status", 'Banned'),
            '2' => Yii::t("status", 'Disabled'),
        ),
    );

    if (isset($value))
        return isset($_items[$attribute][$value]) ? $_items[$attribute][$value] : false;
    else
        return isset($_items[$attribute]) ? $_items[$attribute] : false; 
 }
```

So when viewing users I have good status is displayed (for example : "Enabled"), but when I want to filter by status I have to filter with 1, 2 or 3.

I wanted to know if it was possible to filter by status (active, banned, disabled)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is possible.
You can create scopes like:

```
public function scopes()
{
   return array(
       'enabled' => array(
          'condition' => 'status=0',
       ),
       'banned' => array(
          'condition' => 'status=1',
       ),
   );
}
```

Then in your query you'd have something like:

```
$activeUsers = User::model()->enabled()->findAll();
$bannedUsers = User::model()->banned()->findAll();
```

Also, you can have named scopes:

```
public function statusIs($status)
{
    // you can accept a status string here and translate it in an integer, your choice.
    return $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
       'condition' => 'status = '.(int)$status
    ));
}
```

And use it in your query like:

```
User::model()->statusIs(0)->findAll();// get all enabled
```

Also, using scopes you can query your related models as well, something like:

```
Posts::model()->with('users:enabled')->findAll();
```

should work too.

Just take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes and see more.

L.E:

```
public function getStatuses()
{
   return array(
      '0' => Yii::t("status", 'Enabled'),
      '1' => Yii::t("status", 'Banned'),
      '2' => Yii::t("status", 'Disabled'),
   );
}

public function getStatusesDropDown(array $htmlOpts = array())
{
   return CHtml::activeDropDownList($this, 'status', $this->getStatuses(),$htmlOpts);
}
```

Now that you have the drop down code, in your CActiveForm, or any other form you show this status drop down like:

```
echo $model->getStatusesDropDown();
```

When you select a status from the drop down and you submit the form, the input named `YourModel[status]` will be submitted. This will have a value of 0 or 1 or 2. Next, in you `search()` method, you have to:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    [...]
    if ($this->status !== null && (int)$this->status >= 0) {
       $criteria->compare('status', (int)$this->status);
    }
    [...]
}
```

And that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But now I want to use this research in the search() function of my model, to use $criteria->compare('status', this->status). Could you tell me how you do that?

Comment: define a dropdown with the values being 0,1,2 and the names of your statuses then when your `search()` method will retrieve the values and you can directly compare them as you stated above